# How do I create a MySQL View that reads its data from a different server and database?

Tags: mysql

I have a table test1, which is stored in MySQL database dbtest, on host server_A. I want to create a view V on database MySQL test2, on host server_B. I want to read data from table test2 into view V. and...I'm not allowed to use replication. Can MySQL even read data from another MySQL sever? is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

One of the possible ways to implement this behavior is by using a table with the *FEDERATED* storage engine (as opposed to MyISAM, InnoDB, ..).

This storage is essentially a proxy. Say you have a table '*remote_table*' on database '*remote_db*' on host '*remote_host*'. If you want to use that table as if it was a local table on database '*local_db*' on host '*local_host*', you'd set up a new table '*local_table*' on '*local_db*' with the *FEDERATED* storange engine, and point it to '*remote_table*' on '*remote_host.remote_db*'. It will act as a virtual, proxying table, forwarding statements through the MySQL client API to the remote table and returning results.

Setting up and using *FEDERATED* tables in ludicrously easy.

On the remote_db, you don't need to do anything special, except maybe create a dedicated user for this table, for security reasons, with limited privileges.

On the local_db, you create a new table that mirrors the remote_table:

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    [column definitions go here]
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://remote_user@remote_host:9306/remote_db/remote_table';
```

Those last 2 lines do all the magic - they make this table act as a proxy for a remote table, specified in the `CONNECTION` line.

There are some gotcha's, though - no transactions, no query cache (on the local_host server), slower performance on huge batch inserts, ...

References:
[The MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: i have two table they already created one is test1 and other is test2 in mysql database the test2 table is created on another server and i want create view or read data on my server and that 2 tables are not any relation my aim to avoid duplication ..can you please help if u have any idea ilias..

Comment: Is there anything unclear about my answer? (constructive critisism is always welcome). Anyway, create a table "test2" on the same server as "test1" as a federated table pointing to "test2" on your other server. This way, it will *act* as if it's on the server with test1, but it will *not hold any data whatsoever*. It will proxy all queries to your other server and return the results, as if it were a local table. Avoiding any duplication whatsoever. This federated table can also be used inside views. Please tell me what you don't understand so I can help you, but please read carefully, first...

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2` (
  `pv` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pv`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://root@abc.com/db1/test2';                                                        Thanks ilias for helping me i have created this table on my machine i am fine with that i cant undestand wot is next procedure after that can i insert all values same like sever? or after wot can i do?

Comment: After that, you can mostly forget that the table data is actually on another server. Just use it like any other local table. INSERT's, UPDATE's, DELETE's and SELECT's will just proxy everything to the other server, and return whatever that server returns. If this answer helped you reach your goal, don't forget to upvote and/or accept it; so other people who see this question will know it has received a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Hi sorry i have fire command on my created test2 table but there is not proxy everything to my other server, can i create same view on my local machine. i have created test2 table same like server table and i dont want to touch my server i want same table on my local machine without any duplication i want as like virtual table on my  machine how can i do this and ones again thanks for helping me

Comment: If changes aren't being reflected on the remote server, there might be something wrong with the connection. Did you use a user that's allowed to login from the ip of the server you're creating the federated table on? Did you verify the password? Does that user have insert/update/delete/select/handler permissions?

Comment: sure i am checking i want create same virtual test2 table like server test2 table is it posible?

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what a federated table is. If that doesn't work for you, please explain what you tried and what your results were. You need to try a couple of different avenues before expecting others to do the thinking, troubleshooting and problemsolving for you.